# Query timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure in MS-SQL which takes approx 10 minutes to run directly. When launching it from an asp page I get "Query timeout expired" despite trying to set the script timeout and connection timeout. Any ideas ?

Code sample below.

mypage.asp

```
<% SERVER.ScriptTimeout = 2147483647
Set adoCo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCo.ConnectionTimeout = 12000
adoCo.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=find;Data Source=192.168.1.0; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"

sqlstring = "exec dbo.Prepareme"

Set recordset2 = adoCo.Execute(sqlstring)
recordset2.connectionTimeout = 12000
adoCo.close
Set AdoCo = nothing
Set Recordset2 = nothing %>
```

Comment: `adoCo.CommandTimeout` is what your looking for I think.

Comment: Just trying now, so far so good - thank you !!

Comment: I would suggest that the problem is the procedure, not so much the timeout. A procedure that takes 10 minutes to run on a web page is a huge red flag.

Comment: In SSMS, right click on the Server > Properties > Connections and look for any connection timeouts set.